# Meaning of diamond-shape notes on guitar staff

Tags: guitar, notation, transposition

I am playing a piece for the guitar on the piano and everything sounds fine until I reach the last few notes in the score: all the notes marked with a '19' above the staff and represented with diamonds appear to be in a different key.  Anyone knows what's happening here?

Also, what does the p i a m i p m i mean for the notes that are preceding?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

p-i-m-a indicate which finger to pluck with (thumb, index, middle and ring, the letters come from the Spanish names), and thus are guitar specific.  Similarly the small numbers to the left of the noteheads indicate which left hand finger to use to fret that note.

The diamond shaped notes are natural harmonics. I believe that the way it is notated here is: the note locations indicate the string (e a d g b e low to high) and the numbers above them indicate the fret at which to make the harmonic.  Thus the pitches are

- g 19 = d (+ a fifth +1 octave)
- b 19 = f#
- e 19 = b
- g 12 = g (+ an octave)
- b 12 = b
- e 7  = b (+ a fifth +1 octave)
- a 7  = e

where I've indicated where the sounding note lies in relation to the note indicated by the diamond note head.  The harmonic produced at the 19th fret is the same as the one generated at the seventh.

Comment: Could be artificial harmonic as well,.

Comment: @NeilMeyer but on the picture, it's natural harmonic. Artificial harmonic may have some notes above it.

Comment: Great.  That makes so much sense: I was stuck in my piano-oriented mind and didn't think about harmonics for a second.

Comment: @Dave Is this notation a standard one? I mean, if I see a diamond-shaped note in the high E position, can I be sure it must be played on the first string, or can it be a 5th-fret harmonic on the 6th string? Also, is this notation used with artificial harmonics?

Comment: Usually I've seen it where the note that is sounded is indicated by the diamond note head; e.g. f# from the 19th fret of the b string would be indicated with the notehead on the top line of the staff, usually with an 8va indication, like here: http://www.acousticguitar.com/How-To/Acoustic-Guitar-Notation-Guide.  That's why I hedged in my answer, but interpreting the 19s as fret numbers seemed to be the only thing that made sense.

Comment: The “arm” notation under the notes, short for _armónico/a_, indicates that these are natural harmonics.